# WPF mirror application to two windows?

Tags: wpf, window, multiple-monitors

I have an application with one window. I'd like that window to be replicated/mirrored across two external monitors. (However, either of the monitors should be able to be interacted with, just simple button presses.)

(I could just create two windows and manually make all the same calls, but I'm wondering if there's a way to just 'mirror' from one window to another)

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use the MVVM pattern with two windows.  That would "automatically" give you the functionality you want, if all work is done at the ViewModel and just bound to the same View on both windows.